# how to use Moya RxSwift to get an array of REST merged

Tags: swift, rx-swift, moya

I am trying to learn RxSwift. I had been using Moya and now want to try my hand at RxSwift. Totally confused.

```
 let popServiceProvider = MoyaProvider<PopRESTService>()
    let o1 = popServiceProvider.rx.request(.getPopByCity(city: "London")).asObservable()
    let o2 = popServiceProvider.rx.request(.getPopByCity(city: "Tokyo")).asObservable()

    let pObservables:[Observable<Response>] = [o1, o2]
    let stats: Observable<Response> = Observable.combineLatest(pObservables)
    let m = stats.map({ a in
        print(a)
    })
```

First I get an error on let stats:

Cannot convert value of type 'Observable<[Response]>' to specified type 'Observable'

am I even going in the right direction?

EDIT:

Even this doesn't work. Never first the subscribe:

```
   wServiceProvider.rx.request(.getWeatherByCity(city: "Chicago"))
    .debug()
    .map(Weather.self)
    .subscribe({ (event) in
        switch event {
        case let .success(response):
            print(response)

        case let .error(response):
            print(response)
        }
    })
    .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My misunderstanding of Apple XCTest. I needed to add:

```
                expectation.fulfill()
```

in my subscribe.

```
Observable.combineLatest([o1, o2])
        .map { (responses: [Response]) -> [Weather] in
            responses.map { try? JSONDecoder().decode(Weather.self, from: $0.data) }
                .compactMap { $0 }
        }
        .debug()
        .subscribe(onNext: { (result: [Weather]) in
            print(result)
            expectation.fulfill()

        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `Observable.combineLatest(o1, o2)` variant of `combineLatest` (this form is limited by 8 arguments)

Assuming that type returned from `case getPopByCity(city: String)` might look like:

```swift
struct PopByCity: Decodable {
  let count: Float
}
```

you probably want to implement the request like that:

```swift
Observable.combineLatest(o1, o2)
  .map { (resp1: Response, resp2: Response) -> [PopByCity] in
    let pop1 = try? JSONDecoder().decode(PopByCity.self, from: resp1.data)
    let pop2 = try? JSONDecoder().decode(PopByCity.self, from: resp2.data)
    return [pop1, pop2].compactMap { $0 }
  }
  .subscribe(onNext: { (result: [PopByCity]) in
    print(result)
  })
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

But if you still need an array of requests:

```swift
Observable.combineLatest([o1, o2])
  .map { (responses: [Response]) -> [PopByCity] in
    responses.map { try? JSONDecoder().decode(PopByCity.self, from: $0.data) }
      .compactMap { $0 }
  }
  .subscribe(onNext: { (result: [PopByCity]) in
    print(result)
  })
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

For the second option, keep in mind, that it is not a good practice to send tons of async request at the same time. For many request need to be performed I recommend using [Concat](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) operator or combination of Concat + [Reduce](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/reduce.html) if you have to handle all responses in one place after the last response.

Comment: I tried your code and get the same problem with my other attempts: adding debug() tells me "subscribed" but nothing ever gets run inside .subscribe.

Comment: Hm, not sure I got it right, maybe threre is some issues with performing requests. If I change `o1` and `o2` to an `Observable` that simulates `Single` API call, like 
```swift
    let o1 = Single<PopByCity?>
      .just(PopByCity(count: 5000))
      .delay(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
      .asObservable()
      .debug("o1")
```

Any code you could share, will help clarifying the problem. I don't know how your Model-struct looks like, or how you are mapping `Response` to Model.